Snipping Tool prevents Greenshot from taking screenshots, even after it's been removed
The problem is that I can't get Greenshot to take screenshots. For some reason, some part of the Microsoft Snipping Tool appears when I press the screenshot button of the keyboard, even after I uninstalled it. Here's what I tried so far.
The Snipping Tool is installed.

So I remove it.

And I know is removed because the option in Microsoft Store is "Get" instead of "Open".

But for some reason, when I press the PrtScr button on my keyboard, this pops up.

This utility opening up, even after I removed the Snipping Tool is what prevents Greenshot from taking screenshots, even though it's configured to use the PrtScr button.

I have also disabled the option in windows "use the print screen key to open screen capture" under Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard.
What eles can I do to be able to use Greenshot when pressing PrtScr?

These two programs usually do work together without problems. Reinstall Greenshot and remove it with completely with a tool like Revo Uninstaller.

it's a fresh windows installation, and a fresh greenshot installation. And I don't see how they can work together. The PrtScr button can only be mapped to a single application. Otherwise how it will know what to open?

I use Greenshot with another button than PrtScr.

One more : In Settings > Apps > Installed apps, type "snip" in the search field, click the 3-points menu and select "Uninstall".

it says "we couldn't find anything to show here. Double check your search criteria" when searching for "snip" under Settings > Apps > Installed apps.

Have you tried following the instructions at https://winaero.com/how-to-disable-print-screen-from-opening-snipping-tool-in-windows-11-and-10/amp/

yes, as I said in my post "I have also disabled the option in windows "use the print screen key to open screen capture" under Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard". The instructions just give you different ways of toggling that button.
